# Adobe Shockwave Player PKG installed but I can't find the application

Tags: macos, applications, adobe

I just downloaded adobe swf on my computer. I went through the pkg file and it said that it was installed. The application support scripts are there, but where is the app? Thanks in advance!

I tried installing it twice; one to all users and one the the mac.

Comment: Hi Ethan, Adobe Shockwave Player is a web browser plug-in and there is no app. See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application support scripts are there, but where is the app?

[Adobe Shockwave Player](http://get.adobe.com/shockwave/) is a web browser plug-in, that is, **there is no app**. It installs in:

```
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Shockwave 12/DirectorShockwave.bundle
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/DirectorShockwave.plugin
```

[image]

and, in High Sierra (macOS 10.13), can be enabled and configured in Safari>Preferences>Websites:

[image]

The plug-in is not yet supported in Mojave beta (macOS 10.14).

Answer (score 1):

In the **Installer.app** you can view the list of files that are going to be installed by navigating to `File` -> `Show files`, of pressing <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.